# Why do we say id when reading something in SqLite, but 'id' when creating/updating/deleting a row?

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I am creating a notes app. The user can input a note, and it will get saved to the database/displayed on the screen.

I have a DatabaseHelper class which includes all the CRUD methods(Create, Read, Update, Delete).

When I update a specific note in a table, I have to do it like this:

```
db.update("Note", contentValues, "id='"+id+"'", null)
```

with '' surrounding the user's id.

However, when I am querying to read a note, I don't have to include the '':

```
String fetchOneNote = "SELECT * FROM Note WHERE id="+id;
```

Is there a specific reason for this? It seems like in both, I am referring to the database, so why do I need the ''?

Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't use string concatenation to get values in SQL queries (or part of them) at all but use parameters.

Comment: The ' are unnecessary if id is an integer, but needed if its a string.  But as already mentioned-  don't do this, you're opening up a HUGE security whole.  Look up parameterized querries for how to do it right, and SQL injection for why its a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to enclose a numeric literal in single quotes but single quotes are required for a string literal.

So IF id is numeric there is no need to enclose it in single quotes. However, it doesn't hurt to enclose a numeric literal in quotes.

As such ASSUMING that **id** is numeric then:-

```
db.update("Note",contentValues,"id=" + id,null)
```

will effectively work the same as :-

```
db.update("Note", contentValues, "id='"+id+"'", null)
```

**However**, the recommended use of the SQLiteDatabase `update` method is to utilise the 4th parameter for the where clause parameters which protects against SQLite injection. As such it would be better to use :-

```
db.update("Note",contentValues,"id=?",new String[]{id});
```

The SQLite parser then handles the **id** appropriately, replacing the **?** with the value and protects against SQLite injection.

See https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#literal_values_constants_ and also https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#parameters

- *Although the explanation regarding binding parameters includes:-*

> But because it is easy to miscount the question marks, the use of this parameter format is discouraged. Programmers are encouraged to use one of the symbolic formats below or the ?NNN format above instead.

- *The **?** is commonly used. This is what the `update method` (and other methods) expect.*

  - *It does mean that on occasions you may have to code the same parameterised (bound) parameter twice along with ?'s (as you would if not using bound parameters).*

Comment: Thank you for your response! For this line: db.update("Note",contentValues,"id=?",new String[]{id}); since ? is discouraged and we should use the parameter ?NNN instead, would we use ?4 to hold a spot for the 4th parameter, which we passed in as the id in our update function? Thanks

Comment: Not with SQLiteDataabse methods they build using only the ? NOT with ?NNN. I've rarely seen ?NNN used. e.g. you could have `db.Update("mytable", contentvalues,"a=? OR b=? OR c=?", new String[]{"Fred","Mary","Tom"})` the method replaces the ?'s for you so little chance of a mistake (in theory).

Comment: Thanks. Will it fill in the ? with the highest parameter +1(as stated in the docs -"A question mark that is not followed by a number creates a parameter with a number one greater than the largest parameter number already assigned.")...or will it just fill in the question marks with the array of names we inputted(the sort of more intuitive approach)? Thanks

Comment: It will use the values in the array that is Fred goes into the first ?, Mary into the 2nd and Tom into the 3rd .... (error if the number of ?'s doesn't match the number of parameters).

Comment: Got it thanks. Why is the documentation saying something about taking the highest parameter and increasing it for the "?" parameter ? Is that if we have integers instead of strings? Thanks.

Comment: That's about using SQLite directly via the API. On Android you use the API indirectly through the SQLiteDatabase methods so you have to use what they have implemented to make your life easier.

Comment: Thanks! How do you access SqLite via the API(assuming we are not using Android)? Thanks.

Comment: That depends upon the programming language and typically you then use the API indirectly. SQLite itself uses C++ (SQLite3) see https://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html

Comment: Thanks. So if we were to use C++, then we would be accessing the API directly, and all the parameter documentation applies? Thanks.

Comment: could rather than would as there are probably wrappers for C++ as well. Of course some other languages would allow you to also utilise the C++ interface. However, the wrappers would typically be utilised as they would typically be well proven.

Comment: Thanks. So is the docs on SqLite parameters all irrelevant then considering the wrappers make your life easier, but don't access Sqlite directly?

Comment: yes BUT with the caveat of understand the wrappers (which aren't always that well explained, so sometimes try and learn approach is needed).

Comment: Got it. Thank you for the help!